# Use document.getElementById after loading with Ajax

Tags: getelementbyid

Please help me out here.

I have a file index.php, relevant portion (Jquery is loaded earlier):

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#test').load("table.php");
</script>
```

And a file table.php. If no variables are given, an unfiltered table is shown. When table.php loads, it also loads a select field, like:

```
<select name="testfield" id="testfield" onchange="javascript:setactionfilter();">
<option value="1">Test</option>
<option value="2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

After that, a script to reload table.php in that testdiv with filtered results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setactionfilter(){
$('#test').load("table.php?action=".document.getElementById('testfield').selectedvalue);
}
</script>
```

The problem is that my browser tells me that the getElementById is null, in other words, it can't find my select field in the page.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: there is a dot here `table.php?action=".document`. in your script

Comment: Thanks. Deleted the dot. Still chrome reports "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `.` to `+`

Concatenation is done with `+` in javascript e.g `string3 = string1 + " " + string2`

```
$('#test').load("table.php?action="+document.getElementById('testfield').value);
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it at least reloads the div. But when I echo $_GET['testfield'] with PHP it returns "undifined". Why?

Comment: Fixed it by changing it to .value instead of .selectedvalue! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function is asynchronous, so performing operations that requires the data immediately will fail. Instead, use the callback functionality of the load function:

```
$('#test').load('table.php', function() {
    // Do your stuff here!
});
```

Putting your code in the callback function ensures that `table.php` is loaded and ready when the code is run.

Comment: Well I think that is not what I mean. When a user comes on the page, a standard table is loaded, with the select field within. When the users clicks on the select field and changes the value, the div should be reloaded again, but now with table.php?action=selectedvalue. How do I implement this in a function like above? Sorry for my stupidity, i am a beginner.